# How to make a sorted set with an O(1) random access by index

Tags: java, list, sorting

Need a collection of strings where elements inserted needed to be sorted and also non-duplicate, can be retrieved through index.

- I can use `TreeSet` which removes duplicates and sorts everything in
  order but cannot retrieve through index. for retrieving through
  index, i can make `ArrayList` and `addAll` elements to it, but this
  `addAll` takes lot of time.

or

- I can use an `ArrayList`, insert required and then remove duplicates by some other method, then using `Collections.sort` method to sort elements.

But the thing is, all these take time, is there any straight-way to achieve this, a collection -sorted, non-duplicate, with O(1) random access by index.

Comment: Why don't you just use a TreeSet and then build your SortedList with the SortedList(Collection<>) constructor? SortedSet<> implements Collection<>

Comment: Anything that you do on a computer "take[s] time." Have you measured this particular part of your program and discovered that it takes an *unacceptable* amount of time? And if so, what is "unreasonable" in your case? Hours, seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: 33082 records took 710ms for addAll method, where records can extend upto lakhs, which takes lot of time right? Also building up the Treeset took same 704ms, but that is permissable , but this addAll takes as much time as building taking, so i thought i could cut this cost and make my program run faster.

Comment: 710 ms to add 33k records to an ArrayList is excessive; I would have expected somewhere in the 5ms range. This indicates that yes, you have a problem, but it's probably not one that will be solved by data structures. Please post your code (a SSCCE if possible - see http://sscce.org/) and someone might point you at the real problem.

Comment: one important and unanswered question is: will you add elements to your structure in between retrievals by index?

Comment: no, once i make a Sortedset then, i will add this to list for index retrieval purpose

Comment: if addAll takes too much time, try using Set.toArray().

Comment: main_ary=(String[]) mainset.toArray(new String[length]);
takes same time as  array.addAll(mainset); did

Comment: post the code. Also you can try using hashset to eliminate duplicates, then toArray() and then sorting the array.

Comment: what's the constraint on insertion time?

Comment: "I can use an ArrayList, ..." none of the negative sides conflict with the given time constraints, so that's the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a Data Type in the commons collection called SetUniqueList that I believe meetsyour needs perfectly. Check it out:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/SetUniqueList.html

Comment: Link is broken; updated link here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/SetUniqueList.html

Comment: new links also broken

Answer (score 2):

You can use the second idea:

> I can use ArrayList,insert required and then remove duplicates by some
>   other method, then using Collections.sort method to sort elements.

but instead of removing the duplicates before the sort, you could sort the `ArrayList` first, then all duplicates are on consecutive positions and can be removed in a single pass afterwards.

At this point, both your methods have the same overall complexity: O(N*logN) and it's worth noting that you cannot obtain a sorted sequence faster than this anyway (without additional exploitation of some knowledge about the values).

Comment: Can you quantify how this might be faster than the first option? Because if you break it down by algorithm, you'll find that you are performing an *O(logN)* sort and an *O(N)* copy in both cases.

Comment: @kdgregory: In the TreeSet version you are doing N * O(logN) insertions (or duplicate checks) so O(N*logN) total. In the second version you are doing an O(N*logN) sort + O(N) traversal which is still O(N*logN). The second version however has the added benefit of accessing by index, which is what the OP also wanted.

Comment: Sorry, but i what i've meant is both first & second options are taking time , i'm not quantifying both here....

Comment: @cypronmaya: There is no faster way to obtain a sorted collection than O(N*logN).

Answer (score 2):

The real problem here is that the OP *has not told us the real problem*. So lots of people guess at data structures and post answers without really thinking.

The real *symptom*, as the OP stated in a comment, is that it takes 700ms to put the strings in a TreeSet, and *another* 700 ms to copy that TreeSet into an ArrayList. Obviously, the program is not doing what the OP thinks it is, as the copy should take at most a few microseconds. In fact, the program below, running on my ancient Thinkpad, takes only 360ms to create 100,000 random strings, put them in a TreeSet, and copy that TreeSet into an ArrayList.

That said, the OP has selected an answer (twice). Perhaps if/when the OP decides to think about the real problem, this example of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) will be helpful. It's CW, so feel free to edit it.

---

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class Microbench
{
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    throws Exception
    {        
        ThreadMXBean threadBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        long start = threadBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        executeTest();
        long finish = threadBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        double elapsed = (finish - start) / 1000000.0;
        System.out.println(String.format("elapsed time = %7.3f ms", elapsed));
    }


    private static List<String> executeTest()
    {
        String[] data = generateRandomStrings(100000);

        TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
        for (String s : data)
            set.add(s);

        return new ArrayList<String>(set);
    }


    private static String[] generateRandomStrings(int size)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        String[] result = new String[size];
        for (int ii = 0 ; ii < size ; ii++)
            result[ii] = String.valueOf(rnd.nextLong());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The performance depends on how frequently the elements are added and how frequently they will be accessed by index.

> I can use TreeSet which removes duplicates and sorts everything in order but cannot retrieve through index. for retrieving through index, i can make arraylist and addall elements to it, but this addAll takes lot of time.

List.addAll(yourSortedSet) will take atleast O(n) time and space each time you want to access the SortedSet as List (i.e. by the index of element).

> I can use ArrayList,insert required and then remove duplicates by some other method, then using Collections.sort method to sort elements.

sorting will certainly take More than O(n) each time you want a sorted view of your list.

**One more solution**

If you are not fetching by the index very often then it is more efficient to do it  as follows:

Just store `String`s in a `SortedSet` may be extend `TreeSet` and provide/implement your own `get(int i)` method where you iterate till the ith element and return that element. In the worst case, this will be O(n) otherwise much lesser. This way you are *not* performing any comparison or conversion or copying of Strings. No extra space is needed.

Comment: Storing the strings inside a TreeSet requires O(N*logN) because you have N strings and it takes O(logN) to find it's position by successive comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, do you test map? I mean use your string as key in a TreeMap.

In a Map, it is a O(1) for a key to find its position(a hash value). And TreeMap's keySet will return a sorted set of keys in TreeMap.

Does this fit your requirement?

Comment: Only HashMap has *O(1)* semantics; TreeMap is *O(logN)* for retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

If you are bound to the `List` at the beginning and the end of the operation, convert it into a `Set` with the "copy" constructor (or `addAll`) after the elements are populated, this removes the duplicates. If you convert it into a `TreeSet` with an appropriate `Comparator` it'll even sort it. Than, you can convert it back into a `List`.

Comment: Than first built a treeset in O(nlogn) (Red-Black tree) than convert it into a List in O(n), the first conversion is only required if you have to start with a list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Hashmap you will have solved problem with unique values and sort it by some of sorting methods. If it is possible use quicksort.

Comment: Please note that (1) `HashMap` does not preserve any order; (2) You cannot sort a `HashMap` at all. Quicksort can be of some relevance here, but it's quite limited: as soon as you start updating a collection, almost any other algorithm will do better.

Comment: Okay you may use a LinkedMap this extentions of Map<? key,? value> can be used for determination of unique values and can be ordered by pointers of each element of map

Comment: There's no `LinkedMap` in `java.util`. `LinkedHashMap` is not a good fit for any sorting algorithm. Could you please check your advices first?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using LinkedList (which takes less memory than arraylist) with boolean method which determines if that element is already in the list and a QuickSort algorithm. All structures in java have to be somehow sorted and protected from duplicates I think, so everything takes time...

Comment: 1) LinkedList takes *more* memory than ArrayList. 2) Determining if an element is already in a list is an *O(N)* operation on a LinkedList; it's an *O(N)* operation on a sorted ArrayList, but sorting that ArrayList will be *O(NlogN)* at best; 3) Java provides sort methods built-in to the JDK, and uses MergeSort for lists; 4) I can't even understand the sentence that starts with "All structures in java."

Answer (score 0):

there is two ways to do that use LinkedMap where each element in map is unique or make your own extention of list and override method add

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyList<V> extends ArrayList<V>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5847609794342633994L;

    public boolean add(V object) {
        //make each object unique
        if(contains(object)){
            return false;
        }

        //you can make here ordering and after save it at position 

        //your ordering here

        //using extended method add
        super.add(yourposition,object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the problem of finding element at a certain position in a TreeMap. I enhanced the tree with weights that allow accessing elements by index and finding elements at indexes.
The project is called indexed-tree-map https://github.com/geniot/indexed-tree-map . The implementation for finding index of an element or element at an index in a sorted map is not based on linear iteration but on a tree binary search. Updating weights of the tree is also based on vertical tree ascent. So no linear iterations.